# Cluster workers not listening in debug mode

Tags: node.js

When I run this script in debug mode the workers are created but none of them are listening, the master's `listening` event is never triggered and I can't make any HTTP requests.

When I run without debug mode everything's OK, so the problem is not with the script.

```
var cluster = require('cluster'),
    http = require('http');


if(cluster.isMaster){
    cluster.fork();
    cluster.fork();

    cluster.on('listening', function(){
        console.log('New process is listening');
    });
}
else{
    var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
        res.end('hello');
    });

    server.listen(8080);
}
```

My command line arguments are simply:

- node --debug-brk=59062 testCluster.js (***debug***)
- node testCluster.js (***normal***)

I would appreciate it if anyone can shead some light on this, and perhaps run the script themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because all processes (workers & master) are trying to listen for debug operations on the same port. I think this causes the workers to hang, the processes are started but no code actually runs.

To solve the problem I incremented the port number for each newly forked worker...

```
var debugPort = getDebugPort(),
    inDebugMode = !!debugPort;

var workerArgv = process.execArgv.concat();

if(inDebugMode){
    cluster.setupMaster({
        execArgv: workerArgv
    });
}

function fork(){
    updateArgs(workerArgv, 'debug-brk', ++ debugPort);
    cluster.fork();
};
```

With...

```
function getDebugPort(){
    var args = process.execArgv;

    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i ++){
        var arg = args[i];

        if(arg.indexOf('--debug-brk=') == 0){
            var port = parseInt(arg.replace('--debug-brk=', ''));

            return isNaN(port) ? null : port;
        }
    }
};

function updateArgs(args, name, value){
    var search = '--' + name + '=';

    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i ++){
        if(args[i].indexOf(search) == 0){
            args[i] = search + value;
            return;
        }
    }
};
```

I was surprised that this even works in the Webstorm debugger, where each new worker process opens in it's own tab but still has its logging routed to the master's tab.

Comment: I was unable to get this working in webstorm, but I'm using explicit child_process.fork( rather than cluster.  Do you have any pointers for that?